# What is the importance of defining the classes $C^k$ of functions ?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

What is the importance of defining the classes $C^k$ of functions ? Wouldn't be more natural defining the classes of functions differentiable k-times, with k=0,1,2,...
Why the continuity of the last derivative is so important to justify a specific definition ?

Comment: Somes theorems in analysis genuinely require continuity of the derivative (e.g. you may have problems with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

Comment: See also this MO post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66462/which-functions-of-one-variable-are-derivatives

Comment: You get a well behaved Banach space only if you get one when $k=0$. 

Answer (score 8):

Among the properties that make $C^k$ a nice category, and that have no analog for just differentiable maps, I'd list these (some of whom have already mentioned in the comments):

**1.** *The total differential theorem.* To check that a function of several variables is $C^k$ becomes a matter of partial differentiability in each single variable (and continuity of the partial differentials in all of them).

**2.** *The local inverse theorem.* The core of local differential calculus: checking that a local property holds locally at a point just requires verifying that the analogous property holds for the differentials at that point in the corresponding linear category. This holds for being a local diffeo, a local immersion  or submersion; for transversality of mappings, &c.

**3.** *Characterization. (Converse of Taylor formula).* A map is $C^k$ if and only if it has a polynomial expansion of order $k$ "locally uniformly", with continuous coefficients.

**4.** *Whitney extension theorem.* With a natural notion of $C^k$ smoothness on closed sets, every smooth map on a closed set extends on the whole space.

**5.** *Ordinary Differential Equations.*   $C^k(I)$ is a convenient space for well-posed ODE, starting with the problem of finding an antiderivative, given by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Compare with the difficulty of characterising derivatives of everywhere differentaible functions (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66462/which-functions-of-one-variable-are-derivatives) MO question). Note however that $C^k$ is not so a convenient setting for PDE's, e.g. in potential theory.

**6.** *Functional Analysis.* For any open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ the class $C^k(\Omega)$ is a Fréchet space, embedded as a closed subspace into  $C^0(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^N)$ taking a function into its $k$-jet. Something similar also works for the class of $C^k$ maps between $C^k$ manifolds, that can be embedded in the space of    $C^0$ maps in the $k$-jets.

Comment: I would also add Clairaut's theorem to the list: $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}$ automatically true for $C^2$ functions, but can fail for functions that are merely twice differentiable. (Related to this is the fact that for a $C^1$ function, the strong derivative and the weak derivative agree, whereas this is not necessarily the case for functions that are merely everywhere differentiable.) 

Comment: And to add to point 6: the function space $C^k$ offers not only a qualitative notion of _regularity,_ but also a quantitative notion of _magnitude_ (the global or local $C^k$ norms), and thence a notion of _convergence._  The notion of a sequence or series being convergent in the $C^k$ topology can be used, among other things, to demonstrate the k-times differentiability of a limit or infinite series (cf. the Weierstrass M-test).  This can't be done if one restricts attention only to the notion of k times differentiability without any further control on the k-fold derivative.