# Why is mechanical differentiation so hard to get right?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, tag-removed, symbolic-computation

This question is related to [this question on differentiation/integration](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66377/why-is-differentiating-mechanics-and-integration-art) which asks why differentiation is mechanical but integration is an art.  The answers given all make a huge assumption: that one is trying to differentiate a symbolic expression which denotes **at least** a continuous function, usually in fact assuming it is differentiable.  Which makes sense, from a mathematical point of view: why would one want to differentiate a non-differentiable function?

The problem is, it is actually quite difficult to tell whether a function is in fact differentiable or not.  But, nevertheless, one can *blindly* apply mechanical rules, and still get an answer, which appears to make sense.  My favourite example is $\frac{1}{4i\pi}\ln\left( e^{2i\pi x^2} \right)$ (which is purely real for $x$ real), which both Maple and [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Differentiate(1%2F%284*Pi*I%29*ln%28exp%282*Pi*I*x%5E2%29%2%2C+x)) will happily differentiate to $x$.

So the question is: if differentiation is indeed so easy, why is it just as easy to get completely bogus answers from both Maple and Mathematica on a seemingly simple differentiation problem?

Comment: Unless I am missing some tricky aspect of this problem, both Maple and Mathematica are giving an answer that is numerically correct in the neighborhood of x ~ 0 ... so why is this answer "completely bogus"?

Comment: The function has infinitely many singularities along the real line.  The output has no singularities at all, and no indications that any singularities were encountered or removed.

Comment: Can mathematica possibly interpret a function where the symbolic derivative will not agree with the actual derivative almost everywhere?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the derivative at all. Wolframalpha seems to believe that the given expression is $x^2/2$ when $x>0$, for instance.

Comment: If we adopt the (nearly universal) convention that the logarithm function has a cut along the negative real axis, and stay away from the cut, then Maple and Mathematica agree (and all other computing environments that I know), both numerically and symbolically, that the derivative is simply x.

Comment: This sounds more like a software question to me; apparently the programmers who implemented the algorithms are not taking into account complex variable phenomena, such as multi-valuedness of the logarithm, or the nonexistence of continuous sections of the exponential map $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$. Is this a question that people at MO be able to answer? 

Comment: And, of course, there is a natural sense in which that expression is legitimately $x2/2$... taking $x \mapsto e^x$ to be a function from complex numbers to lomplex numbers (where lomplex numbers aren't merely complex numbers, but are instead complex numbers with chosen logarithms (equivalently, continuous group homomorphisms from $\langle \mathbb{R},+ \rangle$ to $\langle \mathbb{C},\times\rangle$)) and $\ln$ to be a function from lomplex numbers to complex numbers, in the obvious way, they actually are full-on inverses to each other, no quibbles. So the trouble isn't that [to be continued]

Comment: the software is saying something completely bogus; the trouble is that the software is saying something completely reasonable which the mathematical community has been trained to pretend is not, for sake of not wanting to have to think about complex vs. lomplex numbers. Of course, this also manifests in the software being unable to separately specify the single-valued logarithm on lomplex numbers from the multivalued logarithm on complex numbers; it's unclear when the user really does want the latter instead of the former. But this is a design issue, not a difficulty-of-programming one.

Comment: Taking this comment together with the other one referenced makes me wonder whether vonjd perhaps will post a follow-up titled "Differentiation IS TOO mechanical" (http://books.google.com/books?id=Xnv5fXu1vFoC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=Halmos+%2B+%22is+too+mixing%22&source=bl&ots=9Yw7sWbt1m&sig=ZTjBTSIVZu5swW2d-7qaCGWse0M&hl=en&ei=5UnkTaf4NOXM0AHot7G7Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAA).

Comment: (I understand that mathoverflow isn't meant for long discussions, but these comment length restrictions are really onerous; I often find myself abandoning all the nuances of what I'd like to say, simply in order to avoid pushing over the length limit. More innocuously, I find myself wasting a lot of effort trying to think of shorter synonyms for words...)

Comment: An even simpler example would be $log(log(sin(x)))$ which doesn't make sense in the reals yet has a 'perfectly valid' (i.e.. mechanically derived) derivative $cot(x)/log(sin(x))$, which makes sense for certain values $x>0$. Ian Stewart discusses this one in his 'Concepts of modern mathematics' p. 64ff. I agree with L Spice that the question should more go into the direction of "When are we allowed to use these mechanical 'rules' - and when not?"

Comment: @Todd: the logarithm implemented in CAS is not multi-valued, but it does have a branch cut.  The problem is not software, it is one where there is insufficient mathematics available to computer scientists to design a good mechanical differentiation algorithm.  @vonjd: I also believe that the problem is more one of denotational semantics, something which mathematicians tend to avoid by simply 'not writing down' nonsensical expressions rather than trying to tackle them more directly.

Comment: Further information on this topic can be found in the Wikipedia topic "principle branch" ... a good example to consider is the Lambert W function (also discussed on Wikipedia) ... and yes, Mathematica does provide programmatic access to all the branches of the W function (not just the principle branch).   What about the non-principle branches of functions like Log and Sqrt?  It would be possible to add an extra argument specifying the branch, but the overwhelming majority of users would reject this option.  Thus, programs like Mathematica, Maple, Sage, etc. generally 'do the right thing'.

Comment: J Sidles, of course you meant ‘principal’, not ‘principle’, branch.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch

Comment: Doh!  Thank you very much for the corrected link ... that typo jumped out at me immediately after clicking "add comment" ... but comments can't be edited, yah know!  :)

Comment: *subjective and argumentative*?

Comment: @John: copy the comment, delete it, paste, edit and re-post it - but quickly enough that someone's reply won't sneak in!

Comment: If you permit multi-valued functions (i.e. multi-valued logarithm), then you should also permit multi-valued derivatives. 

Comment: @Anixx: "multi-valued functions" is a misnomer.  By their very definition, functions are single-valued.  Otherwise what you have is a relation.  Furthermore, it is a myth that allowing multiple values for branched functions help -- see the many works of James Davenport and/or David Jeffrey on the topic, which amply debunks this myth.